# Xamarin live player visual studio 2017 preview not showing up

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-live-player

I have followed every steps descrived on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/install/.But not getting the live player on device. I found the that **Xamarin for Visual Studio**
version is **4.6.0.295** but for live player it need to be version **4.6.0.560** or upper. I am enable to update that plugin..

My current Visual Studio's version is 2017 15.3 preview 6.
I have checked every relevant question on stack overflow but not get any proper answer to solved this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug preventing it from showing on new installs that should be fixed soon

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100103/important-visual-studio-2017-15-3-preview-users-please-read-if-new

Comment: Thanks @ken...  you save my lots of effort.